# Android App that runs multiple installed apps in a window

Tags: java, android, user-interface, multitasking, multiscreen

I want to ask a crazy yet damn interesting question.

> **Can we create an Android app that can run other installed application in windows (Not Mircosoft ;) it's plural of window )? That windows could be re-sizable , minimized , maximized or closed ?**

It would be a multiscreen app but different from a basic multiscreen app! If it's possible then is there any open source projects/library available for this?

```
Don't down my question before understanding it properly. thanks.
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

> Could we create an android app that can run other installed application in windows (Not Mircosoft ;) it's plural of window ) ? that windows could be resizable , minimized , maximised or closed ?

Only by modifying the operating system itself.

Comment: Ya that's the final choice ! :/ but before that want to know. i think let me ask it here so may be get the answer from STACKExperts (Like you) if it's possible or not! anyways thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can create window like apps, but it is too complex to implement it. But you can do in it in `Sencha Touch ExtJS Framework`, which you can create window like apps. This framework is meant for all mobile platforms.

Comment: It would force me to move from java to HTML5 :(

Comment: No, It will not run in mobile browser,It will run in mobile platform itself.

Comment: Sencha Touch supports all mobile phoe, IOS, android and others

Comment: Ya i know but i have to code in HTML5 thought ExtJS is a java script framework !

Comment: This java script framework will work including mobile platforms

Comment: Are you 100% sure that Sencha would help me short out it ? because i never worked on it before !